# SQL Server Sorting Date With Hours/Mins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a complex date column that I need to sort by in SQL Server 2008

My query:

```
SELECT 
    DivisionName AS Division, StoreNum AS Store, 
    LeadName AS Lead, Type, ChangeType, Changes, 
    UpdatedBy, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), UpdatedDate, 101) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), UpdatedDate, 100), 8) AS UpdatedDate 
FROM 
    m 
WHERE 
    DivID != 0 
ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), UpdatedDate, 101) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), UpdatedDate, 100), 8) ASC
```

The format in the database: `smalldatetime` 2016-01-25 16:50:00

And to the display value, I use:

```
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), UpdatedDate, 101) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), UpdatedDate, 100), 8) AS UpdatedDate
```

My issue: (Hour/Minute Sorting), I need the 7:40PM row at top.

[image]

Different order by attempts:

**1:**     Order by UpdatedDate

[image]

**2:** Order by convert(varchar(10),UpdatedDate, 101) desc, right(convert(varchar(32),UpdatedDate,100),8) asc

[image]

Comment: Your question makes no sense. 7:40PM clearly comes after 11:29AM. If you want them sorted from later to earlier, use `DESC` in your `ORDER BY`.

Comment: No need to convert them to strings to order them.  Just `ORDER BY UPDATEdDate`.

Comment: @SamAxe That returns the same result.

Comment: @KenWhiteI will edit my question with results.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out what you described as complex. Sort by the date. What you're doing is alphabetical (in the character by character sense.)

Comment: @Hanoncs You asked a similar PHP question the other day. I didn't read it all but this appears to be nearly identical in nature.

Comment: conversion makes no sense . simply use order by

Comment: The actual reason I had this issue, is that I was converting to a varchar in the select and using an alias the same as the column name, so when I tried to sort by that column, it was trying to sort by that varchar not the smalldatetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are converting the datetime into Varchar in sort section also..try below query for your output

```
SELECT DivisionName as Division, StoreNum as Store, LeadName as Lead, Type, ChangeType,Changes, 
UpdatedBy, 
convert(varchar(10),UpdatedDate, 101) + right(convert(varchar(32), UpdatedDate,100),8) as UpdatedDate FROM m 
WHERE DivID!=0 
ORDER by UPDATEdDate desc
```

here in the order clause mentioned only the datetime column so it will sort the rows in desc order of the date and time..

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d3cd/2)

Comment: @Hanoncs yes..so it will do sorting by charachter..just use the column name of datetime will solve the issue..hope its fine now..i upvoted ur question